# Return users Min and Max values in single row,

Tags: mysql

I have a table full of user answers to a question.

I want to be able to construct a SQL statement which returns their first answer (min), and their most recent answer (max), ending up with a result like this:

```
user_id | first_answer | last_answer
1       | 50           | 100
2       | 10           | 5
```

...the table looks like this:

```
answer_id | user_id | answer
1         | 1       | 50
2         | 2       | 10
3         | 1       | 100
4         | 2       | 5
```

Sorry I don't have any code to show, but I genuinely have zero idea how to achieve this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

By min and max, I mean the first answer, and the most recent answer for each user.

Comment: what do you mean with min and max? because in your result table they are just first and last answers (not min or max)

Comment: I mean the first entry (min answer_id), and the most recent (max answer_id)

Comment: so then you want 1, 1, 3 instead of 1, 50 ,100? and so on..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a query for that in two steps. First you get first and last answers for each user

```
select  user_id, min(answer_id) min_answer, max(answer_id) max_answer
from    yourTable
group by user_id
```

Then you join that with the original table twice to get the corresponding values for both first and last answer

```
select  t1.user_id, t2.answer as first_answer, t3.answer as last_answer
from    (
            select  user_id, min(answer_id) min_answer, max(answer_id) max_answer
            from    yourTable
            group by user_id
        ) t1
join    yourTable t2
on      t2.answer_id = t1.min_answer
join    yourTable t3
on      t3.answer_id = t1.max_answer
```